# Pandas group by date range with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2          col3
 A      2021-02-01     P
 B      2021-02-12     P
 C      2021-02-08     Q
 A      2021-02-04     Q
 B      2021-02-14     Q
 A      2021-02-15     S
```

The col2 is pandas datetime type. Now I want to group col3 values on col1 and col2(with date date range of +- 4 days, ex: col3 values between 2021-02-01 and 2021-02-04 should be grouped against col1 values)

So the final data frame should look like,

```
col1    col3
 A      [P,Q]
 B      [P,Q]
 C      [Q]
 A      [S]
```

This could be done using a for loop and checking the date time differences but the execution time will be huge, so looking for pandas shortcuts to do this more efficiently.

Comment: There is discussion about `with date date range of +- 4 days`, is possible explain more?

Answer (score 2):

If need defined groups by each 4 days starting by first day of group use:

First create helper column for subtract dates by first value per groups by integer division of `4` and then use it for aggregate lists:

```
df['g'] = df['col2'].sub(df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('first')).dt.days // 4

df=df.groupby(['g','col1'])['col3'].agg(list).reset_index(level=0,drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
  col1    col3
0    A  [P, Q]
1    B  [P, Q]
2    C     [Q]
3    A     [S]
```

Comment: I think //4 does not reflect the OP said +-4days. In additon, the boundary of the date clusters could be a lot harder to define

Comment: Clever use of `// 4` to define the range. I've been enjoying your `groupby` answers today...

Comment: @BingWang - Ya, I use OP example `ex: col3 values between 2021-02-01 and 2021-02-04`, so compare by first value

Comment: shouldn't 1/31 and 2/3, or 1/30 and 2/2 also within 4 days of each other? I mean the boundary is harder to assume to start with multiples of 4

Comment: @BingWang - Yes, if need `+-4` then it is more complicated.

Comment: +-4 is not really well defined, but if you don't want items missing or doubling in groups then its really just an eight day range (with possible offset) which is basically the existing answer